# Creating a Crossfilter “Plugin”

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I tried searching for this and hopefully asking this doesn’t reveal my poor search skills, but it might. Because it seems as though this is a Javascript basic skill.

How to I add a new function to Crossfilter? I can add it to an “instance” of a Crossfilter object, but I can’t figure out how to add it to the “Class”. (I know it’s not really a class.)

This works

var xf=crossfilter(data);

xf.myFunction = _ => ...

But I’d prefer to do it like this (though I know it doesn’t work since Crossfilter isn’t a class) so it’s not specific to a single object but to all Crossfilter objects I create.

Crossfilter.prototype.myFunction = ...

I thought a few posts on jQuery plug-ins would help me adapt an answer but that didn’t seem to get me there as that’s (appears) to be functionality of jQuery, not JavaScript.

http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/

Comment: What do you get when you do `Crossfilter.prototype.myFunction = ...`? If an error, you should add it to the question, if unexpected behaviour, please try to describe it. Some precisions about what you want to do can be wecome too (is your function supposed to access/modify other Crossfilter properties, functions?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually crossfilter is neither a class nor uses prototypal inheritance:

```
function crossfilter() {
  var crossfilter = {
    add: add,
    remove: removeData,
    dimension: dimension,
    groupAll: groupAll,
    size: size
  };
  //...
  return crossfilter;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/blob/master/crossfilter.js)

So there is no way to use inheritance here. To add that method to all instances you have to monkey patch the factory:

```
 {
   const oldCrossfilter = crossfilter;
   crossfilter = function(...args) {
      const instance = oldCrossfilter(...args);
      instance.myFunction = _ => _;
      return instance;
   };
 }
```

Comment: Okay - so I wasn't totally off base in not seeing the "direct" way of doing it. I had to read up on Monkey-Patching a bit to understand what was happening here and given that as an option, it seems like it may be more straightforward to write a function that just takes a `crossfilter` object along with a function (`myFunction(xf, func)`) and modifies the `xf` object by reference. If I did go with the MP though, where am I putting the MP-code you've offered here. I haven't done it before so I'm a bit naïve/lost on whether I gut this in my code, in a few file, etc.

Comment: @Matt the point in monkey patching is to avoid modification on the original source code, so that you can update it with a new version for example (as long as the modifications don't impact your patch, of course). So, this patch should be in your own code, after loading Crossfilter's source, and before you do anything with it.

Comment: Huge help and got me going! I had to add `return instance;` at the end of the `function(...args)` to make the above work. Was that the right thing to do or did I misunderstand what you were presenting?